# Google Page Analytics Showing "/" instead of correct link

Tags: google-analytics

Our Google Page Analytics is showing "/" as the destination URL for many links when in fact those links do not link to "/"  Why is that?  We want to see the correct stats but these links are all registering as a link to the home page and not the page that it actually links to.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you have configured for your Default URL in the Property Settings?

Comment: Not nearly enough information. Maybe you have a single page app that uses the hash mark to indicate pages (which Ga would ignore). But you have to give us more info if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics will break your address 'mysite.com/thispage' into two elements; the hostname 'www.mysite.com' and the page identifier '/thispage'. If you're seeing '/' as a page identifier, the page was actually 'hostname/'. You can see this if you add 'hostname' as a secondary dimension to any report.

You should also check the implementation of analytics on your website; when you click on links, do they actually change the URL? Do they trigger a Page Load?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, I know about the / meaning the hostname.  I'm viewing Page Analytics through the Chrome browser extension.  It works great for some links but several others are just showing as "/."  Some of these links load youtube videos and 1 loads our live chat.